# Multiple grids trying to pass values from one grid to another using e.parameter - Value coming up 'undefined'

Tags: google-apps-script

I will start by saying that I am self taught on Google Apps Script so I do a hack job of coding.  Second, I am trying to learn HTML right now but I have a project deadline coming up so I'm just trying to get by for right now.

I used Google-Apps-Script to build a questionnaire to collect information from our field users.  The way I built the questionnaire is that I use several grids that I set as Visible or not (to hide them) and I do this by using a "back" and "next" button to set Visible true or false.  I am trying to pass a value from a listbox on the second grid to be part of an option in a listbox on the fourth grid but the value from the second grid using e.parameter is putting 'undefined' in the other listbox.

Below is my very long code that is stripped down to have only what is necessary for you to help me.  I know my method of coding is deprecated by Google so is that why it's not working??

```
function doGet(e) {


 ///////////// General Items //////////////////////////
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1TL9puAknBw_ANGuY26l46NKrU1QXvwby8ihfGdpJAjg');
  var app = UiApp.createApplication()
  var panel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('panel');
  var grid = app.createGrid(5, 1).setId('grid').setStyleAttribute("border","2px solid #C0C0C0").setWidth("1000").setHeight("750");
  var gridBackNext = app.createGrid(2, 8).setId('gridBackNext').setWidth("1000");
  var gridPrimary = app.createGrid(22, 3).setId('gridPrimary').setStyleAttribute("border","1px solid #C0C0C0").setWidth("1000").setCellSpacing(3);  
  var gridBase = app.createGrid(22, 3).setId('gridBase').setStyleAttribute("border","1px solid #C0C0C0").setWidth("1000").setCellSpacing(3).setVisible(false);
  var gridExtended = app.createGrid(22, 3).setId('gridExtended').setStyleAttribute("border","1px solid #C0C0C0").setWidth("1000").setCellSpacing(3).setVisible(false);
  var gridVisMerch = app.createGrid(22, 3).setId('gridVisMerch').setStyleAttribute("border","1px solid #C0C0C0").setWidth("1000").setCellSpacing(3).setVisible(false);

//////////////  GRID  /////////////////////////////////
  grid.setStyleAttribute(0, 0, "background", '#3193D0')
  grid.setStyleAttribute(1, 0, "background", '#D1E2F6')  


  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Bids & Exceptions Form').setStyleAttribute('color','white').setStyleAttribute("font-weight", "bold").setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "center").setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '40'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Create LDx Other Exception').setStyleAttribute('color','#2A3B67').setStyleAttribute("font-weight", "bold").setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "left").setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '13'));
  grid.setWidget(3, 0, gridPrimary);
  grid.setWidget(4, 0, gridBackNext);

//////////////////  gridBackNext  ///////////////////////////////////////

  gridBackNext.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('').setWidth('750'))
  gridBackNext.setWidget(0, 1, app.createButton('<< Back').setId('back').setEnabled(false))
  gridBackNext.setWidget(0, 2, app.createButton('Next >>').setId('next').setEnabled(true))

  var backHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('back');
  backHandler.addCallbackElement(gridBackNext);
  app.getElementById('back').addClickHandler(backHandler);

  var nextHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('next');
  nextHandler.addCallbackElement(gridBackNext);
  app.getElementById('next').addClickHandler(nextHandler);


  var checkboxPrimary = app.createCheckBox().setValue(true).setId('checkboxPrimary').setName('checkboxPrimary').setVisible(true)
  var checkboxBase = app.createCheckBox().setValue(false).setId('checkboxBase').setName('checkboxBase').setVisible(true)
  var checkboxExtended = app.createCheckBox().setValue(false).setId('checkboxExtended').setName('checkboxExtended').setVisible(true)
  var checkboxVisMerch = app.createCheckBox().setValue(false).setId('checkboxVisMerch').setName('checkboxVisMerch').setVisible(true)


  gridBackNext.setWidget(1, 0, checkboxPrimary)
  gridBackNext.setWidget(1, 1, checkboxBase)
  gridBackNext.setWidget(1, 2, checkboxExtended)
  gridBackNext.setWidget(1, 3, checkboxVisMerch)

//////////////////  gridBase  ///////////////////////////////////////
  gridBase.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Base Selections').setWordWrap(false).setStyleAttribute('color','#2A3B67').setStyleAttribute("font-weight", "bold").setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "left").setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '20').setWidth("225"));
  gridBase.setWidget(0, 2, app.createLabel('').setStyleAttribute('color','#2A3B67').setStyleAttribute("font-weight", "bold").setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "left").setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '20').setWidth("525"));


  gridBase.setWidget(9, 0, app.createLabel('Sub Program:').setWidth("225"));

  var changeHandlerSubprogram = app.createServerHandler('listBoxSubprogram').addCallbackElement(grid);
  var listBoxSubprogram = app.createListBox().setName('subprogram').setId('subprogram').setWidth("250").addChangeHandler(changeHandlerSubprogram); // create a basic list box with a change handler
    listBoxSubprogram.addItem('');
    listBoxSubprogram.addItem('Spring Individuals');
    listBoxSubprogram.addItem('Underclass Grads');

  changeHandlerSubprogram.addCallbackElement(listBoxSubprogram);
  listBoxSubprogram.addChangeHandler(changeHandlerSubprogram);  
  gridBase.setWidget(9, 1, listBoxSubprogram); 
//grid.setWidget(10, 0)  Leaving as a BLANK   

  gridBase.setWidget(11, 0, app.createLabel('Selling Method:').setWidth("225"));

  var changeHandlerSellingMethod = app.createServerHandler('listBoxSellingMethod').addCallbackElement(grid);
  var listBoxSellingMethod = app.createListBox().setName('SellingMethod').setId('SellingMethod').setWidth("250").addChangeHandler(changeHandlerSellingMethod); // create a basic list box with a change handler
    listBoxSellingMethod.addItem('');
    listBoxSellingMethod.addItem('Family Approval');
    listBoxSellingMethod.addItem('Prepay');
    listBoxSellingMethod.addItem('Proof');

  changeHandlerSellingMethod.addCallbackElement(listBoxSellingMethod);
  gridBase.setWidget(11, 1, listBoxSellingMethod); 
//grid.setWidget(12, 0)  Leaving as a BLANK 


  gridBase.setWidget(13, 0, app.createLabel('Camera Platform:').setWidth("225"));

  var changeHandlerCamera = app.createServerHandler('listBoxCamera').addCallbackElement(grid);
  var listBoxCamera = app.createListBox().setName('camera').setId('camera').setWidth("250").addChangeHandler(changeHandlerCamera); // create a basic list box with a change handler
    listBoxCamera.addItem('LDX');
  changeHandlerCamera.addCallbackElement(listBoxCamera);
  listBoxCamera.addChangeHandler(changeHandlerCamera);  
  gridBase.setWidget(13, 1, listBoxCamera); 
//grid.setWidget(14, 0)  Leaving as a BLANK  

//////////////////  gridExtended  ///////////////////////////////////////

  gridExtended.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Extended Selections').setWordWrap(false).setStyleAttribute('color','#2A3B67').setStyleAttribute("font-weight", "bold").setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "left").setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '20').setWidth("225"));
  gridExtended.setWidget(0, 2, app.createLabel('').setStyleAttribute('color','#2A3B67').setStyleAttribute("font-weight", "bold").setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "left").setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '20').setWidth("525"));

 gridExtended.setWidget(13, 0, app.createLabel('Clicks:').setWidth("225"));

  var changeHandlerClicks = app.createServerHandler('listBoxClicks').addCallbackElement(grid);
  var listBoxClicks = app.createListBox().setName('clicks').setId('clicks').setWidth("250").addChangeHandler(changeHandlerClicks); // create a basic list box with a change handler
    listBoxClicks.addItem('');
    listBoxClicks.addItem('1Click');
    listBoxClicks.addItem('2Click');
    listBoxClicks.addItem('3Click');
    listBoxClicks.addItem('4Click');
  changeHandlerClicks.addCallbackElement(listBoxClicks);
  listBoxClicks.addChangeHandler(changeHandlerClicks);  
  gridExtended.setWidget(13, 1, listBoxClicks); 

  gridExtended.setWidget(5, 0, app.createLabel('Theme:').setWidth("225"));

  var cHTheme = app.createServerHandler('listBoxTheme').addCallbackElement(grid);
  var listBoxTheme = app.createListBox().setId('Theme').setWidth("250").addChangeHandler(cHTheme); // create a basic list box with a change handler
    listBoxTheme.addItem('');
    listBoxTheme.addItem('Environmental');
    listBoxTheme.addItem('Blue Only');
    listBoxTheme.addItem('Grey Only');
    listBoxTheme.addItem('Other Static Background');

  cHTheme.addCallbackElement(listBoxTheme);
  listBoxTheme.addChangeHandler(cHTheme);
  gridExtended.setWidget(5, 1, listBoxTheme);  
//grid.setWidget(6, 0)  Leaving as a BLANK 

  gridExtended.setWidget(9, 0, app.createLabel('Package Offering:').setWidth("225"));

  var cHPackageOffering = app.createServerHandler('listBoxPackageOffering').addCallbackElement(grid);
  var listBoxPackageOffering = app.createListBox().setName('PackageOffering').setId('PackageOffering').setWidth("250").addChangeHandler(cHPackageOffering); // create a basic list box with a change handler

   listBoxPackageOffering.addItem('Base');

  cHPackageOffering.addCallbackElement(listBoxPackageOffering);
  listBoxPackageOffering.addChangeHandler(cHPackageOffering);
  gridExtended.setWidget(9, 1, listBoxPackageOffering);  
//grid.setWidget(10, 0)  Leaving as a BLANK

  gridExtended.setWidget(11, 0, app.createLabel('Class Picture:').setWidth("225"));

  var cHClassPicture = app.createServerHandler('listBoxClassPicture').addCallbackElement(grid);
  var listBoxClassPicture = app.createListBox().setName('ClassPicture').setId('ClassPicture').setWidth("250").addChangeHandler(cHClassPicture); // create a basic list box with a change handler
    listBoxClassPicture.addItem('');
    listBoxClassPicture.addItem('Class Picture');
    listBoxClassPicture.addItem('No Class Picture');

  cHClassPicture.addCallbackElement(listBoxClassPicture);
  listBoxClassPicture.addChangeHandler(cHClassPicture);
  gridExtended.setWidget(11, 1, listBoxClassPicture);  
//grid.setWidget(12, 0)  Leaving as a BLANK


  gridExtended.setWidget(15, 0, app.createLabel('Staff:').setWidth("225"));

  var cHStaff = app.createServerHandler('listBoxStaff').addCallbackElement(grid);
  var listBoxStaff = app.createListBox().setName('Staff').setId('Staff').setWidth("250").addChangeHandler(cHStaff); // create a basic list box with a change handler

  cHStaff.addCallbackElement(listBoxStaff);
  listBoxStaff.addChangeHandler(cHStaff);
  gridExtended.setWidget(15, 1, listBoxStaff);  
//grid.setWidget(16, 0)  Leaving as a BLANK


//////////////////  gridVisMerch  ///////////////////////////////////////

  gridVisMerch.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Visual Merchandising').setWordWrap(false).setStyleAttribute('color','#2A3B67').setStyleAttribute("font-weight", "bold").setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "left").setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '20').setWidth("225"));
  gridVisMerch.setWidget(0, 2, app.createLabel('').setStyleAttribute('color','#2A3B67').setStyleAttribute("font-weight", "bold").setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "left").setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '20').setWidth("525"));

  gridVisMerch.setWidget(3, 0, app.createLabel('Visual Merch:').setWidth("225"));

  var cHVisMerch = app.createServerHandler('listBoxVisMerch').addCallbackElement(grid);
  var listBoxVisMerch = app.createListBox().setName('VisMerch').setId('VisMerch').setWidth("250").addChangeHandler(cHVisMerch); // create a basic list box with a change handler

  cHVisMerch.addCallbackElement(listBoxVisMerch);
  listBoxVisMerch.addChangeHandler(cHVisMerch);
  gridVisMerch.setWidget(3, 1, listBoxVisMerch);  
//grid.setWidget(4, 0)  Leaving as a BLANK 

  panel.add(grid)
  app.add(panel)

return app;
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Function to move values to spreadsheet when Submit button is clicked
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
function back(e) {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1TL9puAknBw_ANGuY26l46NKrU1QXvwby8ihfGdpJAjg');
  var app = UiApp.createApplication()
  var grid = app.getElementById('grid');
  var gridPrimary = app.getElementById('gridPrimary');
  var gridBackNext = app.getElementById('gridBackNext');
  var gridBase = app.getElementById('gridBase');
  var gridExtended = app.getElementById('gridExtended');
  var gridVisMerch = app.getElementById('gridVisMerch');
  var checkboxPrimary = app.getElementById('checkboxPrimary')
  var checkboxBase = app.getElementById('checkboxBase')
  var checkboxExtended = app.getElementById('checkboxExtended')
  var checkboxVisMerch = app.getElementById('checkboxVisMerch')
  var back = app.getElementById('back')
  var next = app.getElementById('next')


  if (e.parameter.checkboxBase == 'true') {
  gridPrimary.setVisible(true)
  grid.setWidget(3, 0, gridPrimary)
  gridBase.setVisible(false)  
  gridExtended.setVisible(false)
  gridVisMerch.setVisible(false)
  back.setEnabled(false)
  next.setEnabled(true)
  checkboxPrimary.setValue(true)
  checkboxBase.setValue(false)
  checkboxExtended.setValue(false)
  checkboxVisMerch.setValue(false)
  }


  if (e.parameter.checkboxExtended == 'true') {
  gridPrimary.setVisible(false)
  gridBase.setVisible(true)  
  grid.setWidget(3, 0, gridBase)
  gridExtended.setVisible(false)
  gridVisMerch.setVisible(false)
  back.setEnabled(true)
  next.setEnabled(true)
  checkboxPrimary.setValue(false)
  checkboxBase.setValue(true)
  checkboxExtended.setValue(false)
  checkboxVisMerch.setValue(false)
  }

  if (e.parameter.checkboxVisMerch == 'true') {
  gridPrimary.setVisible(false)
  gridBase.setVisible(false)  
  gridExtended.setVisible(true)
  grid.setWidget(3, 0, gridExtended)  
  gridVisMerch.setVisible(false)
  back.setEnabled(true)
  next.setEnabled(true)
  checkboxPrimary.setValue(false)
  checkboxBase.setValue(false)
  checkboxExtended.setValue(true)
  checkboxVisMerch.setValue(false)
  }
  return app;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Function to move values to spreadsheet when Submit button is clicked
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
function next(e) {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1TL9puAknBw_ANGuY26l46NKrU1QXvwby8ihfGdpJAjg');
  var app = UiApp.createApplication()
  var panel = app.getElementById('panel')
  var grid = app.getElementById('grid');
  var gridPrimary = app.getElementById('gridPrimary');
  var gridBackNext = app.getElementById('gridBackNext');
  var gridBase = app.getElementById('gridBase');
  var gridExtended = app.getElementById('gridExtended');
  var classPicture = app.getElementById('ClassPicture')
  var gridVisMerch = app.getElementById('gridVisMerch');
  var checkboxPrimary = app.getElementById('checkboxPrimary')
  var checkboxBase = app.getElementById('checkboxBase')
  var checkboxExtended = app.getElementById('checkboxExtended')
  var checkboxVisMerch = app.getElementById('checkboxVisMerch')
  var back = app.getElementById('back')
  var next = app.getElementById('next')

  if (e.parameter.checkboxPrimary == 'true') {
  gridPrimary.setVisible(false)
  gridBase.setVisible(true)  
  grid.setWidget(3, 0, gridBase)
  gridExtended.setVisible(false)
  gridVisMerch.setVisible(false)
  back.setEnabled(true)
  next.setEnabled(true)
  checkboxPrimary.setValue(false)
  checkboxBase.setValue(true)
  checkboxExtended.setValue(false)
  checkboxVisMerch.setValue(false)
  }

  if (e.parameter.checkboxBase == 'true') {
  gridPrimary.setVisible(false)
  gridBase.setVisible(false)  
  gridExtended.setVisible(true)
  grid.setWidget(3, 0, gridExtended)
  gridVisMerch.setVisible(false)
  back.setEnabled(true)
  next.setEnabled(true)
  checkboxPrimary.setValue(false)
  checkboxBase.setValue(false)
  checkboxExtended.setValue(true)
  checkboxVisMerch.setValue(false)
  }

  if (e.parameter.checkboxExtended == 'true') { 
  gridPrimary.setVisible(false)
  gridBase.setVisible(false)  
  gridExtended.setVisible(false)
  gridVisMerch.setVisible(true)
  grid.setWidget(3, 0, gridVisMerch)
  back.setEnabled(true)
  next.setEnabled(false)
  checkboxPrimary.setValue(false)
  checkboxBase.setValue(false)
  checkboxExtended.setValue(false)
  checkboxVisMerch.setValue(true)
  }

  if (e.parameter.checkboxVisMerch == 'true') {
  gridPrimary.setVisible(false)
  gridBase.setVisible(false)  
  gridExtended.setVisible(false)
  gridVisMerch.setVisible(false)
  back.setEnabled(true)
  next.setEnabled(true)
  checkboxPrimary.setValue(false)
  checkboxBase.setValue(false)
  checkboxExtended.setValue(false)
  checkboxVisMerch.setValue(false)
  }  
  return app;
}


//////////////  SubProgram Function  /////////////////////////////
function listBoxSubprogram(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
return app;
}

//////////////  Clicks Function  /////////////////////////////
function listBoxClicks(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
return app;
}

//////////////  Selling Method Function  /////////////////////////////
function listBoxSellingMethod(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

if (e.parameter.SellingMethod === '') {
app.getElementById('Staff').clear()
app.getElementById('VisMerch').clear()
}

if (e.parameter.SellingMethod === 'Prepay') {
app.getElementById('Staff').clear()
app.getElementById('Staff').addItem('').addItem('No Staff').addItem('Staff 1').addItem('Staff 2')
app.getElementById('VisMerch').clear()
app.getElementById('VisMerch').addItem('')
app.getElementById('VisMerch').addItem('S16 '+e.parameter.camera+' '+e.parameter.Theme+' '+e.parameter.SellingMethod+' '+e.parameter.clicks+' '+e.parameter.Staff)
app.getElementById('VisMerch').addItem('S16 '+e.parameter.camera+' '+e.parameter.theme+' '+e.parameter.SellingMethod+' '+e.parameter.clicks+' '+e.parameter.staff+' - Head Count')
}

if (e.parameter.SellingMethod === 'Family Approval') {
app.getElementById('Staff').clear()
app.getElementById('Staff').addItem('').addItem('No Staff').addItem('Staff 1').addItem('Staff 2')
app.getElementById('VisMerch').clear()
app.getElementById('VisMerch').addItem('S16 '+e.parameter.camera+' '+e.parameter.Theme+' '+e.parameter.SellingMethod+' '+e.parameter.clicks+' '+e.parameter.Staff)
}

if (e.parameter.SellingMethod === 'Proof') {
app.getElementById('Staff').clear()
app.getElementById('Staff').addItem('').addItem('No Staff').addItem('Staff 1').addItem('Staff 2').addItem('Staff 4')
app.getElementById('VisMerch').clear()
app.getElementById('VisMerch').addItem('S16 '+e.parameter.camera+' '+e.parameter.Theme+' '+e.parameter.SellingMethod+' '+e.parameter.clicks+' '+e.parameter.Staff)
}

return app;
}

//////////////  Camera Function  /////////////////////////////
function listBoxCamera(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
return app;
}

////////////  Theme Function  /////////////////////////////
function listBoxTheme(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
return app;
}

//////////////  Package Offering Function  /////////////////////////////
function listBoxPackageOffering(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
return app;
}

//////////////  Class Picture Function  /////////////////////////////
function listBoxClassPicture(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
return app;
}

//////////////  Staff Function  /////////////////////////////
function listBoxStaff(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
return app;
}

//////////////  VisMerch Function  /////////////////////////////
function listBoxVisMerch(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
return app;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your code and it would appear that in your next and back functions your re-declaring app. It will have no context of app in your get method as they were declared locally to the function and again in the back and next functions. I'm not up to speed on google apps but you possibly need to look into changing your logic so that the app is global e,g var app at the top of your script and then all your sub functions reference this global variable. Put the creation of the app in a function and return a temp version back to the global version and then in your functions like back and next reference the app and i think this will sort out most of your undefined issues. This is definitely the case in standard javascript.

Comment: I made those changes but it still seems to be showing undefined.  Thank you for the tips.  I'll take anymore from you or anyone else still.

Comment: Is the page getting reloaded between each call back? as this won't help. If you are redirecting your end user between these calls then the global concept is lost. Does google apps have the concept of ajax/jquery updates?. It also looks like you are trying to use e and access properties. If i remember the javascript correctly this is just the event object that fired the event. To use e you have to trace back up to get the associated element that fired the event.